# How to connect AWS elasticache redis from Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

How to connect AWS elasticache redis from Node.js application ?

Answer (score 1):

You're connecting to Redis. The fact that it's a managed AWS service is not really that important in this respect.

So, use a Node.js package that implements a Redis client interface, for example:

- [redis](https://redis.js.org/)
- [node-redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `ioredis`
and stablish a connection like this

```
  const Redis = require('ioredis')
  const redis = new Redis({
      port: 6379,
      host: 'your-redis-host',
      connectTimeout: 10000 // optional
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try connecting using ioredis.

```js
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var config = require("./config.json");

const redis = new Redis({
  host: config.host,
  port: config.port,
  password: config.password, // If you have any.
  tls: {}, // Add this empty tls field.
});

redis.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Redis client is initiating a connection to the server.');
});

redis.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Redis client successfully initiated connection to the server.');
});

redis.on('reconnecting', () => {
  console.log('Redis client is trying to reconnect to the server...');
});

redis.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

//check the functioning
redis.set("framework", "AngularJS", function(err, reply) {
  console.log("redis.set ", reply);
});

redis.get("framework", function(err, reply) {
  console.log("redis.get ", reply);
});
```